# CodeIgniter: The configuration file ion_auth.php does not exist.

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I have been using modules in my project is written with CodeIgniter.

**What I have**

```
Folders
-->application
  -->cache
  -->config
     -->config.php (configuration file for auth, I copied the codes to config.php)
  -->controllers
  -->core
  -->errors
  -->helpers
  -->hooks
  -->language
  -->libraries
     -->auth's libraries files.
  -->logs
  -->models
  -->modules
     -->admin
        -->controllers
           -->auth.php
        -->models
           -->ion_auth_model.php
        -->views
           -->auth
               -->login.php
     -->home
  -->third_party
  -->views
-->assets
-->system
```

**What the problem is**

When I go to localhost/home/auth/login.php, an error message is occurred. On the screen is written

An Error Was Encountered

The configuration file ion_auth.php does not exist.

I guess the problem is about the iounauth configuration file will be moved config folder before setup. I didnt moved it to config folder. Instead of it, I copied all the codes from that file, to the config.php

So how can I solve this problem? I need to see the login screen instead of this error message. I think I should change some lines on auth.php in *controller* folder. Because I am using config.php instead of ionauth.php for *config* folder.

Comment: There are many common issues loading a custom library, first, check if the library is loaded, try to load this on your controller with $this->load->library('ion_auth'); load it in autoload config file in codeigniter, Check if the class is declared with Capitalize, if you are using Codeigniter 3 please read the changes, there are a lot of changes and the traditional library loading has really been changed !

Comment: I check all you said but nothing changed

Comment: ion_auth.php exist in folder config ? also, why you dont make your own auth library? is much easier than ion_auth.

Comment: Have a look at the structure of files and folders for ion_auth here and compare with yours https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Comment: I don't want to use ion_auth.php in config folder. (It is not my choice. :) ) I copied all codes from ion_auth.php and I pasted them to config.php in config folder.

Comment: Good, so declare this to the Library and thell ion_auth Library that the config init is not on ion_auth.php and is on config.php !

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the reasoning for not using the ion_auth.php in the config folder? Also, with the copied config have you just copied straight from the `ion_auth.php` or have you added `['ion_auth']` index in front of all the array declarations?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a quick scan of the ion_auth Library and model and the easiest thing to do would be:

1. Remove `$this->load->config('ion_auth', TRUE);` from both the library and model.
2. do a string replace in both the library and model:

FIND: `, 'ion_auth')` REPLACE WITH: `)`

I have done a quick scan of the files and I can't see anywhere where this would break anything but just be careful when you're doing it (maybe do it one at a time).

The above to steps should allow you to use the ion_auth config items in your `config.php`

Please note that I have not tested this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this issue when move my web to linux server, it solved by renaming **config/Ion_auth.php** to **config/ion_auth.php**